# Paperclip Direct to S3 Invalid Content Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

When I upload my file directly to S3, take that URL and pass it to Paperclip for saving in the model, Paperclip detects the incorrect `content_type` of `application/octet-stream`. Why?

My controller method looks something like this:

```
def update
  @model.update({
    video: URI.parse(URI.unescape(clip_params[:video_url])),
    thumbnail: URI.parse(URI.unescape(clip_params[:thumbnail_url]))
  })
end
```

and I validate `content_type` in my model like this:

```
validates_attachment :video, content_type: { content_type: 'video/mp4' }
validates_attachment :thumbnail, content_type: { content_type: 'image/png' }
```

yet I still receive an error from Paperclip stating that the `content_type` of my file is invalid. Why is it not reading the correct content type when I pass in a URL?

Comment: I am tracking down the same error right now, which seems to have occurred after an upgrade to Rails 4.2. I'm on Paperclip 4.3.0 and Rails 4.2.2—how about you?

Comment: There's a bunch of discussion around this here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/labels/Spoof%20related

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315658/setting-the-content-type-in-direct-to-s3-upload-using-rails-and-jquery-file-uplo

Comment: I'm seeing this too - happened when I updated gems going to Rails 4.2.2, including Paperclip. The problem goes away when I force Paperclip back to version 4.2.1 (so I don't think it's a duplicate of the question linked above from a year ago)