# Converting .txt file to .xml ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, type-conversion, text-files

I have a custom file type (.map) that I am unzipping from a Gzip file and then writing to a new file in order to pass it along to Paperclip and upload to s3.  My problem is that the type should be an xml, while it is saving as a text document instead with all xml formatting correct.  I need a way to convert it into the xml type and then save that as a new File object before passing it along.

Here is my code so far:

```
  Zlib::GzipReader.open(f.tempfile) do |gz|
    puts gz.orig_name
    @tmp = File.new(gz.orig_name, "w+")
     while chunk = gz.read(16*1024) do
       @tmp.write(chunk)
     end  
  end  
  reader = @tmp.read 


  s = location.posts.create!( 
    subject: @email.subject,
    from: @email.from[:email],
    mapfile: @tmp)    
}
```

ideally i will be passing mapfile the xml type file, but right now it seems to be text

**Update**:

So now I have set my post.rb to do this, and added a name attribute to post containing the original file name:

```
has_attached_file :mapfile, 
        :preserve_files => "true",
        :path => 
             ':rails_root/non-public/system/:id/:basename.:extension',
        :url => '/:class/:id/mapfiles',
        :s3_headers => lambda { |attachment| {'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename =  #{attachment.name}"}}
```

And this works perfectly!

Comment: When you say the "type", do you mean the content-type identified by Paperclip?  The file extension?

Comment: @NickVeys The content type is identified as text, and it saves as if it were a .txt file, so that when I go to download it on the index page it brings me to a page which just displays all of the xml code rather than downloading the file.  I need it to save as if it were an xml, and all the xml formatting is already done so i dont need to do any of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about `Content-Type'.  When you save a file to the filesystem, you can't set this: the system will decide what to use based on the file extension and possibly by analysing the contents, if it's a text file.

However, you can set the content type when you serve a file to someone's browser, and when you upload it to S3.  See here for the latter [Setting the Content-Type in direct to S3 upload using Rails and jQuery File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315658/setting-the-content-type-in-direct-to-s3-upload-using-rails-and-jquery-file-uplo)

Comment: see update... this helped, any ideas how to solve the new problem?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it by the time you had seen it!  Thanks for the help!