# setting content type while loading image to aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use this heroku tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) for my first app. I've spent a week on this and have figured out the minute details of this complex process and have lost most of my remaining hair in the process. However one last bit of of setting content type while uploading my avatar is remaining.

I've tried following the post on stackoverflow([Setting the Content-Type in direct to S3 upload using Rails and jQuery File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315658/setting-the-content-type-in-direct-to-s3-upload-using-rails-and-jquery-file-uplo)) to set content_type of the file before uploading to aws but I get 403 forbidden error when I try to do so. Can you please advise.? The default content type that gets loaded without the above change is binary/octect-stream .

AWS.rb is given

```
AWS.config(access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] )

S3_BUCKET = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']]
```

User controller has the pre-signed post-

```
@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read).where(:content_type).starts_with("")
```

Script in new user form is given below -

```
                <script>
$(function() {
  $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
   var fileInput    = $(elem);
   var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
   var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
   var progressBar  = $("<br><div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    var fd           = <%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>;
   fileInput.after(barContainer);
   fileInput.fileupload({
   fileInput:       fileInput,
   url:             '<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>',
   type:            'POST',
   autoUpload:       true,
   formData:         fd,
   paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e.   name="user[avatar_url]"
   dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
   replaceFileInput: false,
   limitMultiFileUploads: 1,
   maxFileSize: 999000,
   acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,

   progressall: function (e, data) {
     var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
     progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
   },
   start: function (e) {
     submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

     progressBar.css('background', 'green').css('display', 'block').
      css('width', '0%').
      text("Loading...");
    },

    done: function(e, data) {
     submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
     progressBar.text("Uploading done");

    // extract key and generate URL from response
     var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
     var url   = '//<%= @s3_direct_post.url.host %>/' + key;

    // create hidden field
    var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
    form.append(input);
  },
  fail: function(e, data) {
    submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

    progressBar.
      css("background", "red").
      text("Failed");
  },
   add: function (e, data) {
      fd["Content-Type"] = data.files[0].type;  
  data.formData = fd;
  data.submit();
    }


  });
 });
});

 </script>
```

I've also tried unsuccessfully setting aws bucket policy but that did not help -

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Principal": "*",
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bcuket-name"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Any pointers will be helpful!
TIA!

Comment: This question is pretty noisy, but I don't see where you are generating the necessary `<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/png">` (or whatever the content type is supposed to be).  Is that here?

Answer (score 0):

If you get 403 that means the POST request is rejected. You should allow POST for your bucket.

At the moment you don't allow POST. I usually do it with CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You may want to change the origin to your own domain to prevent requests from other sources.

Comment: 403 Forbidden != CORS issue.

Comment: I didn't say it was CORS issue

Comment: Your answer is to change CORS configuration.  If this "fixed" a non-CORS issue in the past, it might be a good idea to go back and re-evaluate those circumstances, because there's no way this should change the actual bucket or user policy permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. I figured out the issue. For others who come across this post, the code I've provided in my original post should work as it is without the bucket policy. I'd another add:function (e, data) {} in the code I was testing and that was doing some other file type checking and was the real culprit.

Michael - the content type is being set in add: callback function.

Lukasz Muzyka - I've the same CORS setting..

Thanks anyways for your help!

Comment: I wasn't able to edit my answer due to some reason. I just wanted to add to my answer that the bucket policy in my original post is NOT required to make the code work.